# Change of author sequence after accept with shepherding

Tags: computer-science, authorship

Is it ethical to change the author sequence in paper that has been accepted with shepherding at an ACM conference? How likely is it that the shepherds will raise questions on such a change?

Comment: In your comment to Buffy's answer, you mention a fact that completely changes the question: Your co-authors have changed (or planned to change) the authorship order *without your consent*. That is surely unethical. However, it is not the shepherd's job to ensure that everybody has given consent - normally, when the authorship order is changed, this implies that everyone is OK with the change.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Thank you -- yes, I do recognize that this is unethical. Unfortunately, after talking to my PhD advisor, I felt that fighting against this would be very complicated. My PhD advisor is not an author of this paper, and luckily we completely understand each other. He also agreed that it is unethical, but thinks as a just graduated student, this is a distraction that is best avoided.

Comment: I don't think that there would be any fighting required. You can just say that you refuse to accept the new order, and announce that you will get in touch with the program chairs if they should change it. However, this will have a price: the paper might not be published at all, and you will surely burn your bridges with that group of authors. So your advisor is probably right that it's not worth it.

Comment: "You can just say that you refuse to accept the new order" -- I did precisely that, but they simply refused to listen. But I restrained myself from taking the next step of contacting the program chairs. It would harm the career of other authors in the paper who I felt really had no role in this drama, except for the professor. I did mention to them that I will never again collaborate with their group.

Comment: I see, so it's really not about avoiding fighting, but about avoiding undesirable consequences. Sounds like the right decision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you know the shepherds and can ask them. But I suspect that if the authors all agree on a change the conference won't object provided that it doesn't come so late as to require changes to websites or proceedings. But in general, order of authorship should be up to the authors.

I might change this opinion if shepherds had made specific advice about authorship, but I've never seen that done. But still, the paper belongs to its authors.

Comment: Maybe I should have worded it in somewhat more detail. I found that my co-authors are pushing me down the author list after acceptance (at shepherding stage). I do not consent to this change. But if I do complain to the PC Chairs, there is a good chance that the paper's acceptance will get withdrawn. I am hoping that the shepherd would object to this change. If they specifically ask about my consent, I would of course be obliged to say that I did not.